# How to use spring oauth source to build project?

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to understand how spring-security-oauth2, therefore trying to run sparklr2 sample with source code of spring-security-oauth project.

downloaded the source code of spring-security-oauth, add it to sparklr2 build path, remove spring-security-oauth2 from maven pom, then run the project.

failed with file not found exception, missing GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.class, what does it means? am I suppose too create a GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.java? or missing some annotation dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, do not need to build with source code, just build with maven dependency, click "attach source code", then eclipse will be about to set breakpoints and debug.

P.S. need to download source code of spring oauth using git.